# using volley in widget android

Tags: android, android-widget, android-volley

I would like to use `volley` lib in my widget but bitmap always is null !

All my code :

http://pastebin.com/0wi4pX0N

my code :

```
   imageLoader.get("http://www.shadyab.com/assests/images/upload/yuu1.jpg", new ImageLoader.ImageListener() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(ImageLoader.ImageContainer response, boolean isImmediate) {


            if(response == null){
                Log.e("response", "response");
            }else if (response.getBitmap() == null){
                Log.e("getBitmap", "getBitmap");
            }else{
                remoteViews.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.img_view_main_image_widgets,response.getBitmap());
            }
        }
```

I always get :

> 01-21 17:50:41.066: E/getBitmap(13554): getBitmap

Comment: Post the FULL error stacktrace, Did you include the `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` in your manifest?

Comment: Can you show how you init you volley?

Comment: I have not any errors, just I get my log error. yes,I added this permission in my manifest.xml

Comment: @Braunster my initial volley is ok, because I am using this lib to my custom listview (Loading images into imageviews).